Meta Ads SKAN Attribution Window
Regarding Meta Ads API action_attribution_windows parameter, what is the window for skan_click and skan_view? Is it same as default 7-day click-through and 1-day view-through? In the reporting tool, the SKAN attribution only showed value for skan_click, but when using API to get skan_click and skan_view, there are values for both. Why is skan_view ommited in Meta Ads reporting tool? Thanks.
enter image description here
